# Cursor keep jumping to the left (to the start)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm trying to add a different behaviors and converters. but no matter what I'm doing, the cursor keeps going back to the start.

For example, I'm trying to use behavior to prevent more than 1 whitespace in a row.

So when the user typing more than 1 space (in a row), it should remove the 2nd space and leave only 1 (`text.Replace("  ", " ")`) and the cursor should stay at it's position.
But instead, the cursor jumping back to the start.
Its doing it also with different behaviors.

How can I make the cursor to stay at its position so if the user type "This   is nice". it will be "This is nice" (and not "is niceThis ").

I hope I explained myself correctly.
Thank you so much.

I just created a fresh app (still doing the same)
This is my code

xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProj.Behaviors"
             x:Class="TestProj.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Entry Placeholder="Hello">
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <local:WhiteSpaceBehavior />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
            </Entry>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Behavior Class:

```
namespace TestProj.Behaviors {
    public class WhiteSpaceBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
            entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
        {
            entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
        }

        private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var entry = (Entry)sender;
            var newText = e.NewTextValue;

            if (ContainsConsecutiveWhiteSpaces(newText))
            {
                newText = RemoveConsecutiveWhiteSpaces(newText);
                entry.Text = newText;
            }
        }

        private bool ContainsConsecutiveWhiteSpaces(string text)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i]) && char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i + 1]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private string RemoveConsecutiveWhiteSpaces(string text)
        {
            var newText = text.Replace("  ", " ");
            if (newText.Contains("  "))
            {
                newText = RemoveConsecutiveWhiteSpaces(newText);
            }
            return newText;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: is it happening on a real device or on the emulator? because i can't reproduce

Comment: on a real device (i didn't try on the emulator)

Comment: I just checked it on the emulator, It's doing the same thing.

Comment: Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue when using `.NET 7`. The cursor keeps jumping to the start point of the `Entry` when you entered more than one whitespaces. Fortunately, it's being fixed on `.NET 8`.

To fix it, you can reset the `CursorPosition` after removing the extra whitespaces. And the cursor should stay at its position as expected.

```
private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
      var entry = (Entry)sender;
      var newText = e.NewTextValue;

      if (ContainsConsecutiveWhiteSpaces(newText))
      {
            newText = RemoveConsecutiveWhiteSpaces(newText);
            entry.Text = newText;
      }

      //key is here
      entry.CursorPosition = entry.Text.Length;
}
```

Comment: Even when I do this "entry.CursorPosition = (sender as Entry).Text.Length;" like you did, It still behaving the same way from some reason.

Comment: I just checked it on .NET 8 (instead of .NET 7) and its working. how can I fix it to work on .NET 7?

Comment: @Noah Yes, it's working on .NET 8 and only having issues with .NET 7. You can use .NET 8 instead to fix it. And I can make it worked when reset `entry.CursorPosition`. Are you testing it on Android or iOS simulator? Versions?

Comment: I'm testing it on physical android device (10 - API 29) and emulator (13 - API 33). I don't know why `entry.CursorPosition` is not working for me. I prefer to stay with .NET 7 for now. thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @Noah No worries, you can also try `entry.CursorPosition = entry.Text?.Length ?? 0;`.